# how to add in placeholder sequential addition number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When i click add string btn > i clone first tr whith input in table and add in this table, and i need add +1 number in placeholder copied element.How determine last placeholder. Before copy and add in new copied placeholder/
this html table

```
<div class="matrix_a_cover">
   <table class="matrix_a brackets" id="matrix_a">

          <tr>
           <td class="str_inp">
             <input type="text"  placeholder="a1,1">
           </td>
            <td class="str_inp">
             <input type="text"  placeholder="a1,2">
           </td>
         </tr>

          <tr>
           <td class="str_inp">
             <input type="text"  placeholder="a2,1">
           </td>
            <td class="str_inp">
             <input type="text"  placeholder="a2,2">
            </td>
         </tr> 

        <tr>
           <td class="str_inp">
             <input type="text"  placeholder="a3,1">
           </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
             <input type="text"  placeholder="a3,2">
          </td>
         </tr>  

        <tr>
           <td class="str_inp">
             <input type="text"  placeholder="a4,1">
           </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
             <input type="text"  placeholder="a4,2">
          </td>
         </tr>


       </table>
   </div>
```

this code copy element

```
    $('.add_str').click(function(){
  if ($("#check_mtrx_a").prop("checked")){
    $('.matrix_a tr:first').clone().appendTo('.matrix_a'); 
  }else if($("#check_mtrx_b").prop("checked")) {
    $('.matrix_b tr:first').clone().appendTo('.matrix_b'); 
  }
});
```

and if need example how work this all link  [serjo96.github.io/matrix](http://serjo96.github.io/matrix)

Comment: What is the issue here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Trigger the following function when you update the table

```
function placeHold() {
$('tr').each(function(i,v){//loop each row
  $(v).find('td').each(function(x,d){//loop each colon in that row
    $(d).find('input').attr('placeholder','a'+i+','+x);//change the input placeholder
  });
});
```

Note: this will start from a0,0

Comment: How to start counting from 1.1?

Comment: its very hard to do that you need complex math `$(d).find('input').attr('placeholder','a'+(i+1)+','+(x+1));`